# good tutorial on using ruby-debug to switch threads in a ruby program

Tags: ruby, multithreading, debugging, fork, ruby-debug

I have some forks in my Rakefile and I want to dive into what each process does and I was wondering if there are any good tutorials out there on debugging a ruby program that has threads **with a debugger**. I'm looking for something that shows you how to attach to a newly created thread and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RubyMine IDE has good process debugging and it's pretty intuitive. I'm going to use that.

Here's a quickstart guide they give you
http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/quickstart/